# Media files don't work in template on Django localhost

Tags: python, django

Trying to set up media locally. In template generated path appears to be correct and looks like this `/media/event_img/1058`

```
<div style="height: 201px; background: url('{{ event.image.url }}')  no-repeat; background-size: cover;background-color: #091026;"></div>
```

But still, no picture is shown(It exists for every item, I checked manually), and if enter `http://localhost:8000/media/event_img/1058` I'll just get 404 error, URL pattern not found.

In settings.py :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'files/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

What may be wrong? Where to look for the issue? As I understand to the documentation this setup is enough to output media files.

Comment: Try this `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "files/media")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the valid full path to the `media` directory.

In `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'files/media')
```

In `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This requires a directory named `files` where `manage.py` is, in which is containing directory `media` and in it will be the uploaded files.

Ref: [MEDIA_ROOT docs in Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root)